# Need to Add Custom Button and Related action in System->Config->Custom section as field

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration

I am Adding Custom Section in System->Config Tab.

I need to add Button as Field and its related action which I need to perform. But I cannot find on google for button all example provide other field option but hard to get button example.

Other Section Working fine but I am not able to add button and related action (filepath) which call on click.

```
<fields> 
  <goldprice translate="label"> 
    <label>GoldPrice</label>                   
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>  
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default> 
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website> 
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
    <comment>Gold Price per 1gm</comment> 
  </goldprice> 
  <run translate="label">
    <frontend_type>button</frontend_type>
    <frontend_model>/adminhtml_system_config_customfield</frontend_model>
    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
  </run> 
</fields>
```

My Config File Like Below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <LetsNurture_CustomGrid>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </LetsNurture_CustomGrid>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <customgrid>
        <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Block</class>
      </customgrid>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Model</class>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <customgrid>
        <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Helper</class>
      </customgrid>
    </helpers>
    <events>
      <admin_system_config_changed_section_gold> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <customgrid>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>UpdatePrice</method>
          </customgrid>
        </observers>
      </admin_system_config_changed_section_gold>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

And Customfiled.php like below

```
class LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Customfield extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $url = $this->getUrl('catalog/product'); //

        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
                    ->setType('button')
                    ->setClass('scalable')
                    ->setLabel('Run Now !')
                    ->setOnClick("setLocation('$url')")
                    ->toHtml();


        return $html;
    }
}
```

But it gives me Warning like this **"failed to open stream: No such file or directory"**

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<frontend_model>` path goes to to Blocks (instead of Models).

Incidentally, even though it’s named a `model` class but we have to create it as a Magento Block class since this is how the other built in front end model classes are implemented.

As well as, it is used for template output so it’s appropriate to create a block class for this.

Example

```
<frontend_model>NAMESPACE_MODULENAME/adminhtml_system_config_customfield</frontend_model>
```

So

Create `Customfield.php` under `.../NAMESPACE/MODULENAME/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config`/ with the following content:

```
class NAMESPACE_MODULENAME_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Customfield extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{


    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {       
        $html = parent::_getElementHtml($element);
       //Write your custom html here
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: getting this error Warning: include(Mage/LetsNurture/CustomGrid/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Customfield.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory ( I dont know why its searching in core even this placed in local)

Comment: Please add following under global tag in config.xml:  <blocks>
     <Mymodule>
         <class>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block</class>
     </Mymodule>                         
 </blocks>

Comment: I have Added that But Even this is happening

Comment: Is your cimpilation is disbaled ? If not then disbale it and try,,And have you clear your cache ?

Comment: Thanks for Help, I will Try and reply because by now working on other.

Comment: Its also not working below is my config file <global>
    <blocks>
      <customgrid>
          <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Block</class>
     </customgrid>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
      <customgrid>
        <class>LetsNurture_CustomGrid_Helper</class>
      </customgrid>
    </helpers>
   </global>

Comment: Is there any requirement to create Block.php or Index.php under block folder ?

Comment: No,there is no requirement of Block.php,also please update your question with config.xml and Customfield.php